# Is the union of countable sets (S)U(S x S)U(S x S x S)U..... countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider a set X = $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$$S^n$, where $S^n$ = S x S x S x S ... (n times)

Question: Is X countable?

My attempt:

For two countable sets S and T, I found it easy to prove that their Cartesian product is countable. I defined a function f: S x T -> $\Bbb N$, 
f(m,n) = $2^m$$3^n$ and proved it was an injection, then defined a function 
g: $\Bbb N$ -> S x T, g(n) = (0,n) and showed it was also an injection.

Therefore by Cantor-Bernstein, there exists a bijection. So | S x T | = |$\Bbb N$| and S x T is countable.

Is there some way to extend this idea to the infinite union of Cartesian products of this countable set S ? My first thought was to define some function
f($s_{1}$, ..., ) and in some way show that the injection that existed for S x T will always exist for any amount of Cartesian products. 
I also know that the for some countable sets A and B, C = B-A
--> AUB = AUC and its easy to show that AUB is countable (considering both cases: C is finite or C is infinite and countable)

Completely stuck on marrying the two ideas though! Any help appreciated

Comment: countable union of countable sets is countable. Just consider a matrix, with i-th row containing elements of the i'th set...

Comment: "Just". The proof uses the axiom of choice.

Comment: Are you hinting at Cantor's diagonal argument? or is the matrix something else entirely